# express and fetch: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

I am using express, fetch and firefox.
This is the code

```
async updateTutorial() {
const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.currentTutorial)
    };

  await fetch("https://localhost:9000/tutorial/update" , requestOptions);


}
```

In Firefox I see this error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource
I do not know what kind of problem it is.

Comment: You are trying to open an SSL connection to localhost. I doubt valid certificate exists for you host. if it's still an error with `http` protocol, probably no one is listening on that port.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you must use http instead of https.

To fix the cors error, you have to specify `mode:"no-cors"` in request options.

```js
async updateTutorial() {
 
          const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "no-cors",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.tutorial)
        } 

        await fetch("http://localhost:9000/tutorial/update" , requestOptions);
   }
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: mode:"no-cors" give a js error:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"no-cors" | "cors" | "navigate" | "same-origin" | undefined'

Comment: try `mode: 'no-cors' as RequestMode,` or `RequestMode:'no-cors'`

Comment: mode:"no-cors" works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am using now this:

```
async updateTutorial() {
 
          const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.tutorial)
        } 

        await fetch("http://localhost:9000/tutorial/update" , requestOptions);
   }
```

In Firefox I get the same error, in Edge and Chrome it works. I have only one AddIn in Firefox installed from HP. This I can't deinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the form tag with a div. Now there is no error.
I have forgotten to mention that I get this log stamp:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
```

Comment: Very bizarre, I had the same problem on Firefox with a somewhat different stack -- HTMX and Alpine JS at the front end. Same error: TypeError when doing a fetch/post of JSON data, and same fix: change a form element to a div. Can only speculate Firefox was trying to turn the data into x-www-form-urlencoded or something. Would never have thought to try such an obscure fix, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using https://localhost:9000/tutorial/update. For localhost use http://localhost:9000/tutorial/update

Comment: I can use only http. But then I get a CORS error. I do not if the issue is in firefox or jexpress? Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf http://localhost:9000/get/tutorials

Comment: I found an issue. I used still https. But not I am using http and I have still the same issue.

Comment: I have still te issue:

[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <Anonymous onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< 
Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
 > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Comment: Use http and then add the origin of your frontend in the cors in express.

Comment: I think I have configured cors. but I get this:
POST
 
scheme
 http
host
 localhost:9000
filename
 /tutorial/update/33
Adresse
 127.0.0.1:9000
Status404
Not Found
VersionHTTP/1.1
Übertragen496 B (158 B Größe)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin

 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
 http://localhost:8080
Connection
 keep-alive
Content-Length
 158
Content-Security-Policy
 default-src 'none'
Content-Type
 text/html; charset=utf-8
Date
 Sun, 09 May 2021 19:50:04 GMT
Keep-Alive
 timeout=5
Vary
 Origin
X-Content-Type-Options
 nosniff
X-Powered-By
 Express

Comment: With post man the url works, but not with firefox.

Comment: And it works also with edge and chrome. But not with firefox.

Comment: have you added the url http://localhost:8080 in the cors?

Comment: I get this error: Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <Anonymous onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< 
Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
 > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
The code I use const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));